# How to debug a spring boot app in VS Code with command line arguments?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I've tried to create a VS Code launch configuration which passes command line arguments to a Spring Boot app.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
"configurations": [
   {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - DemoApplication",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "com.jackdry.processors.kafkalz4_compress.DemoApplication",
      "projectName": "kafka-lz4_compress",
      "vmArgs": "-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=-color=red"
    }
  ]
```

But when I press "Debug" in VSCode, `-color=red` isn't being printed. Can anybody help?

If useful, the command which "Debug" actually invokes is:

```
cd /home/jack/jackdry/processors/kafka-lz4_compress ; /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:38675 -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=-color=red -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @/tmp/cp_3noz6bed0u43t5tl3jj9cqoel.argfile com.jackdry.processors.kafkalz4_compress.DemoApplication
```

Comment: `-color=red` should not be a *VM argument*, but a *program argument*. --- If you run the code on the command-line, the location in the command string makes the difference: `java <vm args> DemoApplication <program args>`

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch). --- **`args`** - The command-line arguments passed to the program. --- `vmArgs` The extra options and system properties for the JVM.